# Jsoup - how many KB it takes?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I have for example:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();
String title = doc.title();



Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com")
  .data("query", "Java")
  .userAgent("Mozilla")
  .cookie("auth", "token")
  .timeout(3000)
  .post();




Response response1 = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com").method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .data("name", "peksak")
                .execute();
```

How can I check in these three examples, how much they received the following KB from the internet?

I use this in my Android application. For internet I use WI-FI in my mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can simply get the length of the document and check it's length which is in bytes:

```
Log.e("TAG", "Document size is " +doc.outerHtml().length());
```

With the third example:

```
Log.e("TAG", "Document size is " +response1.body().length());
```

Comment: But what if in html are images?

Comment: @peksak Jsoup doesn't retrieve images it only fetches the html code. However if the link itself was an image perhaps you could try with `response.bodyAsBytes().length()`.

Comment: Ok, but i want get all KB uses to get data from my application

Comment: @peksak Again, images are not parsed/rendered by Jsoup. It only receives the html source. `length` should be more than enough to measure how much Jsoup has downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can do an http header request and get the size of each image. Just grab all the images on the page using jsoup, iterate through them and make the request.